# Privacy-Preserving User Tracking Across Systems with Homomorphic Encryption or hashing

Tags: encryption, hash, homomorphic-encryption, blind-signature

I'm working on a project where we have three different software systems—let's call them A, B, and C.
Systems A and B handle user data identified by phone numbers and want to send user actions to System C for tracking purposes. The goal is to achieve user tracking across systems while maintaining privacy through the use of homomorphic encryption.

Constraints:

- A and B should send user phone numbers to C in a way that prevents retrieval of the real phone number.
- The sent value from A and B for the same phone number should be exactly equal.
- The sent value should not be reversible using methods like brute force.
- No direct data sharing (except the algorithm itself) should occur between the systems.
  Current Approach:
  We've explored the use of homomorphic encryption, specifically blind signatures, to achieve this privacy-preserving tracking. A provides a blind signature on a commitment to the phone number, which is then homomorphically encrypted by C for tracking.

Question:

- Does the current approach seem suitable for privacy-preserving user tracking across systems?
- Are there alternative solutions or improvements to achieve the same goals while respecting the outlined constraints? Something like using hashes in a way that satisfies our constraints.

I appreciate any guidance or insights into achieving a robust and privacy-preserving solution for user tracking across systems. Thank you!